# Building nested filters via JSON (javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, filtering

I have a bunch of filtering options that use Jquery to update the DOM on a simple page that displays a list of rendered "stuff" generated by a JSON object. Each of the filters works really well independently ([see fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DPFff/))  however, I want them to be more connected. I.E. Lets say I filter by gender, then I want to search for a name. Or, If I filter by min age, then filter by activity status. My Filtering functions look like this

```
function sortByAge(value) {
    document.getElementById("range").innerHTML= value;
    var data = getData();
    var length = data.result.length;
    var htmlSlug = "";

    for (var i=0; i< length; i++) {
        if (data.result[i].age >= value){ 
            htmlSlug += writeHTML(data,i);
        }
    }
    if (!htmlSlug) htmlSlug = "Nothing Found";
    $('.data-container').html(htmlSlug);
}

function writeHTML(data, i) {
    //this gets called any time we need to build html to the DOM
    var active = "";
    if (data.result[i].isActive == true) {
        var active = "active";
    }
    var slug = '<div class="member-card-container '+active+'">'+
            '<div class="info">'+
                '<span class="name">'+data.result[i].name+'</span> '+
                '<span class="gender">'+data.result[i].gender+ '</span> '+
                '<span class="age">'+data.result[i].age+'</span>'+
                '<span class="latitude">'+data.result[i].latitude+'</span>'+
                '<span class="longitude">'+data.result[i].longitude+'</span>'+
            '</div>'+
            '<div class="address">'+data.result[i].address+'</div>'+
        '</div>';
    return slug;
}
```

again, see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DPFff/)

Answer (score 1):

Modify your filter function to accept the JSON data as a parameter and return the filtered list.  Do not write the HTML inside of the filter functions.

Create a write HTML function that accepts the JSON as a parameter, loops over the list and writes all the elements out to the page.

If you do that, you will be able to call the filtering functions in sequence, passing the return value (JSON list) of the previous one into the next filter.

Finally, call your write HTML function to write the result into the page.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
function byAgeAsc(r1,r2) { return r2.age - r1.age; }
function byAgeDesc(r1,r2) { return r1.age - r2.age; }

var data = data.result.sort(byAgeAsc).filter(function(r) { return r.age > value } );
```

`data` set will be sorted and filtered and ready to be rendered. For example by mustache.js or my [kite.js](https://code.google.com/p/kite/) template engines.